# Do I need to level up my Charmander for battling?

Tags: pokemon-series

I have a perfect IVs Charmander, with all moves I want. Do I need to EV train him to battle? Because all pokemon are automaticaly adjusted to 50 lv when battling.

Comment: Asking whether you have to level him up and asking whether you have to EV train him are very different. Which do you mean?

Comment: Are you asking if pokemon are given equal EVs when battling other trainers in a flat-level battle?  There ARE other reasons to train your charmander beyond EVs, but it'd be better if we understood the exact question you're asking (which seems to be about EVs and the effects of level adjustment on them).

Comment: Its a good idea for competitive. I think you are assuming you must level to EV train. Assuming you're playing sixth gen, you can use Super Training.

Comment: @StrixVaria has to be online battling since nothing else auto-kicks you to 50 (even battle maison only kicks you DOWN to 50), but this should be cleared up a bit in the question if true (which I'm 99% sure it is).

Answer (score 1):

For online fights? Yes, EVs matter in online fights so while level grinding doesn't matter (though why would you use a Charmander instead of a Charizard), you do need EVs to have the best possible stats. Remember you can use Super Training to raise IVs in gen 6, so you don't necessarily have to grind standard EV training (both methods are pretty fast now though, thanks to Hordes).

Answer (score 0):

You should take the trouble to level it: If someone ever challenges you to a Flat battle, you will be glad your Charmander is leveled up to L50! Flat rules don't automatically level up all Pokémon, so your Charmander will stay at its current level if it's less than that.

Also: if you plan to play in tournaments, please be aware that they use Flat rules.